# XeLaTeX engine in MikTeX broken?

Tags: xetex, miktex

After a fresh installation of `MiKTeX` 22.3 portable on a Win 10 machine I can no longer compile the following simple document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[times]{fontsetup}
\usepackage{altsubsup}

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{First section}

Your text goes here.

\begin{equation}
E_{max} = \frac{C_[50] \cdot E_[max]}{V_[max] + \sqrt{C_[80]}}
\end{equation}

\subsection{A subsection}

More text.

\end{document}
```

Konsole output is here:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (MiKTeX 22.3 Portable) (preloaded format=xelatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(Namenlos-2.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(D:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\tex/latex/base\size11.clo))
(D:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\tex/latex/fontsetup\fontsetup.sty
fontsetup: Easy font setup by Antonis Tsolomitis
(D:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty
(D:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty
(D:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
(D:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xetex.def ()
! Argument of \__sys_tmp:w has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
                                                  
? 
Der Prozess wurde vom Benutzer abgebrochen
```

Can somebody please confirm or shall I open a ticket on the MiKTeX bug tracker?

Comment: looks as if extractbb can't be called, how do you start xelatex? Do you use the terminal provided by miktex?

Comment: I started xelatex from the menu items offered in TeXworks. But same observation if I call xelatex.exe in cmd.exe

Comment: start a terminal from the portable context menu as described here https://miktex.org/howto/portable-edition. Then type there `extractbb --version`. What do you get?

Comment: This is extractbb Version 20211117

Copyright (C) 2008-2021 by Jin-Hwan Cho and Matthias Franz

This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

Comment: Start xelatex from that terminal and then show the log-file so that one can see the versions.

Comment: the log file is too long to be included here. How can I share the log file?

Comment: it shouldn't be too long. Your error happens around line 50.

Comment: This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (MiKTeX 22.3 Portable) (preloaded format=xelatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(c:/users/de016581/OneDrive - Sanofi/Desktop/Namenlos-2.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(D:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\tex/latex/base\size11.clo))
(D:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\tex/latex/fontsetup\fontsetup.sty
fontsetup: Easy font setup by Antonis Tso

Comment: you killed the application. Compile again and when the error happens type `x` on your keyboard and then hit `enter`. Then copy the log-file in your question.

Comment: There is no error anymore. It compiles through. I don't understand. That's why I said the log file is too long.

Comment: well so it looks as if it works if you are in the miktex terminal. Now try if it works in texworks if you start texworks from the portable context menu.

Comment: it works in TeXworks.

Comment: so everything is fine. Simply start texworks throught the context menu. And if you want another editor start it through the terminal of the context menu. Then everything is correctly initialized.

Comment: OK, great. Then it was just a "user error". I started TeXworks via shortcut and not via MiKTeX console. Hope to memorize that. Thanks for your help.